# Launch one app from another

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I'm trying to launch one mono application from another in MonoDroid.

Below is the Activity trying to receive the intents

```
[Activity(ScreenOrientation=ScreenOrientation.Portrait, Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView, Intent.CategoryLauncher })]
public class SplashScreenActivity
```

This is the class that is creating a notification that should launch the other app.

```
 var notification = new Notification(2130837697,
                notificationBodyText,
                System.Environment.TickCount);

 Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
 i.SetComponent(ComponentName.UnflattenFromString("com.myapp.wahoo"));
 i.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryLauncher);
 i.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

 PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(Application.Context, 0, i, 0);
        notification.SetLatestEventInfo(Application.Context,
                "",
                notificationBodyText,
                contentIntent);

 var nm = (NotificationManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Application.NotificationService);
        nm.Notify(2131099716, notification);
```

The app picker is appearing without my app being there. I think my IntentFilters are incorrect but I'm not sure what they should be? Ideally it would be a custom filter so that it launches straight away.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced the Intent with the below and it worked fine.

```
Intent i = Application.Context.PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage("com.myapp.wahoo");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

This worked well for me when I tested between two apps i created myself. Once I know the package name will this always work, or is there a way to prevent someone from launching your app